# CT fourier Transform Proof

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

I am confused trying to understand the Proof of Fourier Transform from Oppenheim book *Signals and Systems*. I am pasting the equations directly from the book:

> $$\widetilde{x}(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_ke^{jk\omega_0t} \tag{4.3} $$
>   $$a_k=\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}\widetilde{x}(t)e^{-jk\omega_0t}dt \tag{4.4} $$
>
> where $\omega_0=2\pi/T$. Since $\widetilde{x}(t)=x(t)$ for $|t| < T/2$, and also, since $x(t)=0$ outside this interval, eq. $(4.4)$ can be
>   rewritten as
>
> $$a_k=\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}x(t)e^{-jk\omega_0t}dt=\frac{1}{T}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x(t)e^{-jk\omega_0t}dt$$

1. My question is In the last equation on the L.H.S, there is no
   $\widetilde{x}(t)$ but it was mentioned in the eq. $(4.4)$
2. And then we have: $$Ta_k= \left.\frac{2 \sin(\omega T_1)}{\omega}\right\rvert_{\omega =
   k\omega_0}$$ That is, with $\omega$ thought of as a continuous variable, the function ($2\sin\omega T_1/ \omega$) represents envelope of $Ta_k$.
   Here I want to know what is meant by envelope?
   I want to add more details from the book exactly " Specifically we have plot $T_0a_k$ rather than $a_k$ and we have also modified the horizontal spacing in each plot. here is the plot "[image]
   3) I want to know that how $T_0a_k$ will be drawn in continuous?

Comment: 1. Since $\widetilde{x}(t) = x(t)$ (as they claim), they have exchanged it. 2. The envelope is the "outline" of a function, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(waves)) for examples and definitions.

Comment: @DanielR, 1) if I assume the term you mentioned is correct then in the integral it $-T/2 to T/2$ and then changed to $-\inf to +\inf$, why it is?
2) yes envelope is the outline but it will be constructed using $Ta_k$

Comment: 1) Since $x(t)=0$ for $|t| > T/2$, the integration limits can be extended to $\pm \infty$. I will have to leave the other questions to someone else.

Comment: @DanielR, Can you check part 3?

Comment: "I will have to leave the other questions to someone else."